# PyPy SqlAlchemy cx_Oracle and binary search

Tags: sqlalchemy, cx-oracle, pypy

I'm trying to run SqlAlchemy on oracle using PyPy.

I have installed all the libraries and I'm using [cx_oracle_on_ctypes](https://github.com/lameiro/cx_oracle_on_ctypes).
Everything is working except when I'm trying to search a binary field (RAW), I'm getting this exception:

StatementError: (exceptions.AttributeError) 'module' object has no attribute 'Binary'.

After a bit of debugging I have found that on file /usr/local/lib/pypy2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py
line 833 there is this statement: 
DBAPIBinary = dialect.dbapi.Binary

But dialect.dbapi has no 'Binary' member but it does have 'BINARY'.

Any idea what I can do?

By the way, using it is working fine using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the module, thanks for reporting it.

I have just pushed a fix to github, so if you can retest and follow-up using the github issue tracker, that would be great.